# Use conditions in MySql select queries

Tags: mysql

I want to get the same column in my database depending on the different values in other columns. In my table I have multiple records for same NIC.

If the 'TransferType'=1, then I want to get the 'StartDate' as First Appointment regardless of what the 'Current' is.

If the 'Current'=Yes , then I want to get the 'StartDate' as it is regardless of what the 'TransferType' is.

I want one row as my output for each NIC. I want to get the 'StartDate' from the row where transfer type=1 as First Appointment. For the same output I want 'StartDate' from the row where current=yes as Start Date itself.

Is this possible? Can anyone help?

Comment: Let us help you, read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Share some sample input and expected output to understand problem .

Comment: if a nic has a row where transfer type = 1 and another row where current = 'yes'  what do you want displayed? Both rows or 1 row?

Comment: I want one row as my output for each NIC. I want to get the 'StartDate' from the row where transfer type=1 as First Appointment. For the same output I want 'StartDate' from the row where current=yes as Start Date itself.

Answer (score 1):

As i understand on behalf of your question you want to use condition in mysql 
to use IF statement in mysql you can specify like this

```
if('TranseferType' = 1 ) Then
   SELECT 'StartDate' FROM tablename WHERE yourcolumn;
else if('Current' = 'Yes')
    SELECT 'StartDate' FROM tablename WHERE yourcolumn;
 end if;
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to use IF-statements in MySQL. Please look at this article: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_if.asp

Not sure how your database looks like, but here's an example

```
IF('TranseferType'=1)  THEN SELECT 'StartDate' FROM yourtable WHERE yourcolumn;
ELSE IF('Current'='Yes')  SELECT 'StartDate' FROM yourtable WHERE yourcolumn;
END IF;
```